# Continuous Message Sending in C#

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm new to C#, and I am programming my first big project, a Discord bot.
The idea is that the bot scans through comments, waiting for the word Cthulhu, and once someone says Cthulhu, the bot sends a message. However, in it's current state, it never stops sending messages. I suspect there's something wrong with my conditional, but have no idea how to fix it. How should I modify my code to fix this?

This is my code, I have the NuGet packages discord.net and discord.commands installed:

```
    discord.MessageReceived += async (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Message.RawText.Contains("Cthulhu") )
                await e.Channel.SendMessage("*Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn*");
        };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your bot is talking to itself :-D

Try this:

```
discord.MessageReceived += async (s, e) =>
{
    if (!e.Message.IsAuthor && e.Message.RawText.Contains("Cthulhu") )
        await e.Channel.SendMessage("*Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn*");
};
```

Comment: Ooooh, that makes sense. Thanks for the help!